# increment and decrement in program using two threads in java through synchronized blocks and methods

Tags: java, multithreading

I want that when the dec() calls it must make two decrements and then its decremented value will pass to inc() and then increment by 1 so that a time come when the decremented value equal to zero and it stops the program..
Code is here

```
package thread_array;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.util.Scanner;


  class A extends Thread {
    public static int count;
    public static int a, b;
    Thread t;
    public static int i;
    A(int i) {
      synchronized (this) {
        a = i;
        System.out.println("Value of a " + a);
        count = a;
        System.out.println("Value of count " + count);
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
        new B(count);
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
      inc();
    }

    public synchronized void inc() {
      try {
        if (count != 0) {
          synchronized (this) {
            System.out.println("Before Incrementing pre " + count);
            ++count;
            System.out.println("Incrementing pre " + count);
            System.out.println("Incrementing in value of p " + count);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
          }
        } else {
          System.out.println("Count values cannot be negative");
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // ignore this
      }
    }
  }

  class B extends Thread {
    public static int count;
    public static int a, b;
    Thread t;

    public static int i;
    B(int i) {
      a = i;
      System.out.println("Value of a in class B " + a);
      count = a;
      t = new Thread(this);
      t.start();
      new A(count);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
      dec();
    }

    public synchronized void dec() {
      try {
        if (count != 0) {
          synchronized (this) {
            System.out.println("Before Decrementing pre " + count);
            b = count--;
            System.out.println("Decrementing first " + count);
            count--;
            System.out.println("Value of second count: " + count);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("p out" + count);
          }
        } else {
          System.out.println("Count values cannot be negative");
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // ignore exception
      }
    }
  }

  class Thread_array extends Thread implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int z;
      System.out.print("Enter your desired number: ");
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      int dj = input.nextInt();
      int[] array = new int[dj];
      for (z = 0; z < array.length; z++) {
        array[z] = 0;
        System.out.print(" " + array[z]);
      }
      System.out.println();
      new B(dj);
      new A(dj);
    }
```

Comment: This is an extremely messy question, please consider posting a SSCCE or such. http://sscce.org/

Comment: "My program has no errors but it doesnot provide me the required output."  And this sentence is false.  ;-)

Seriously, though, please clean up your code (remove blank lines and lines that are commented out, fix indentation).  Please also explain what you expect to see as the output, and what the actual output is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how your program does what you want; every new A() creates a new B() which creates another new A(). Your code seems to loop spawning objects and threads! Did you omit a guard that would not spawn additional objects when the passed parameter was non-positive?

```
Enter your desired number:  4
0 0 0 0
Value of a in class B 4
Before Decrementing pre 4
Decrementing first 3
Value of second count: 2
p out2
Value of a 2
Value of count 2
Value of a in class B 2
Before Decrementing pre 2
Decrementing first 1
Value of second count: 0
p out0
Value of a 1
Value of count 1
Value of a in class B 1
Before Decrementing pre 1
Decrementing first 0
Value of second count: -1
p out-1
Value of a 0
Value of count 0
Value of a in class B 0
Count values cannot be negative
Value of a 0
Value of count 0
Value of a in class B 0
Count values cannot be negative

...
```

the fact that yout t.start() calls are not followed by t.join() calls makes me believe your code is at best non-deterministic.